# What is default "length/values" of "bit" data type in PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, null, bit, notnull

**Questions**:

**1**. What is the default length/values of bit data type in PostgreSQL?

**2**. What is the default length/values of bit data type in SQL Server?

**3**. What is the by default column values(NULL/NOT NULL) in PostgreSQL?

**4**. What is the by default column values(NULL/NOT NULL) in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.**(refer below msdn link)

Bit means 1 bit, its value either 0 or 1, while select or insert condition, we use True for 1 and False for 0.

Its length is 1 and values will be eigher True(1) or False(0).

For sqlserver

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx

For postgresSql

[how does postgres handle the bit data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218170/how-does-postgres-handle-the-bit-data-type)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html